# How can I aggregate date data with EntityFramework but without skipping entries with no data?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

How can I aggregate data by week with EntityFramework but without skipping weeks for which there is no data? So, basically if there is no data for given week - I want to get 0 or NULL as a result for that week.

Comment: I think you can but have to use a cursor, a better solution is to aggregate data by week with a groupby then fill in the blanks in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreeing with Luke's comment above, if you know the weeks included in the search, can you just push your results onto a pre-filled week->result Map of some type initialized to zero?

A quick google shows this smarter than me guy likes this answer too:

http://thenullreference.com/blog/analytical-queries-using-entity-framework-over-date-ranges-using-linq/